# NVL2 use in Before Report of Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I'm trying to use NVL2 in before report but it is not working here is my code in which I'm using.. Please identify my error and help me out.. This query is running correct in toad but in Before Report not works
ThankYou

```
SELECT L.CUSTOMER_NO,
         L.CUSTOMER_NAME,
         ROUND (SUM (NVL (DEBIT, 0) - NVL (CREDIT, 0)), 0) BALANCE
    FROM AR_CUSTOMER_LEDGER L,
         AR_CUSTOMERS C,
         SM_SALES_PERSONS SP,
         AR_CUSTOMER_SALE_PERSONS ACSP
   WHERE     L.COMPANY_ID = NVL ( :COMP, L.COMPANY_ID)
         AND L.BRANCH_ID = NVL ( :BRANCH, L.BRANCH_ID)
         AND CUSTOMER_NO = NVL ( :CUST, CUSTOMER_NO)
         AND L.CUSTOMER_TYPE = NVL ( :C_TYPE, L.CUSTOMER_TYPE)
         AND L.TRAN_DATE <= NVL ( :END_DATE, SYSDATE)
         AND L.CUSTOMER_NO = C.CUSTOMER_ID
         AND C.CUSTOMER_ID = ACSP.CUSTOMER_ID(+)
         AND SP.SALES_PERSON_ID =  NVL2 ( :SALE_PERSON, ACSP.SALES_PERSON_ID, SP.SALES_PERSON_ID)
GROUP BY L.CUSTOMER_NO, L.CUSTOMER_NAME
  HAVING SUM (NVL (DEBIT, 0) - NVL (CREDIT, 0)) <> 0
ORDER BY BALANCE DESC
```

Comment: Do you exactly know about the values of `:SALE_PERSON` ..? Btw, prefer using explicit joins among tables rather than comma-seperated tables list after `FROM` clause .

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Query you posted - as is - can't work in Before Report trigger; trigger is PL/SQL, so SELECT requires an INTO clause, and there's none here.

Comment: @Littlefoot I'm trying to give parameters with this query not inserting data so when I compile with this query error shows "no function with name NVL2 exits in this scope". But this query runs in toad

Comment: Which Oracle Reports version is it?

Comment: @Littlefoot Oracle Reports 11g

Comment: OK, it is a version whose engine should recognize NVL2. Huh, no further ideas, sorry.

Comment: *But this query runs in toad* . Are you sure both databases are the same ( connection from TOAD and from Reports ) ..?